# Inspiring from GENERATED TALEND CLASS and Reuse in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, request, talend

I would like to get the value of  from context in a new [java simple class] by inspiring from the seconde generated [talend class] :

I couldn't get filepath value because TALEND CLASS seems a little bit difficult to me ^^

> > My new java class

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
    import java.io.FileInputStream;
    import java.io.FileReader; 
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.InputStreamReader;
    import sapphire.util.DataSet;
    
    
    public class LHCM_FX {
     
            
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           
// Trying to get filepath here from context as TALEND JAVA GENERATED CLASS DO      
          String filepath = "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Test/";

             System.out.println("xmldataset=" + parseFXFile(filepath+"0.txt").toXML()); 
                 
       }
    
    
        public static DataSet parseFXFile(String filepath) {    
        
         // Something Codes Here
     
        }
```

> > TALEND GENERATED CLASS where filepath is declared

```
import java.io.BufferedOutputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import routines.LHCM_FX_ROUTINE;
import routines.TalendString;
import routines.system.IPersistableRow;
import routines.system.ResumeUtil;
import routines.system.TDieException;
import sapphire.util.DataSet;

public class LHCM_FX {
   public final Object obj = new Object();
   private Object valueObject = null;
   private static final String defaultCharset = Charset.defaultCharset().name();
   private static final String utf8Charset = "UTF-8";
   private Properties defaultProps = new Properties();
   private LHCM_FX.ContextProperties context = new LHCM_FX.ContextProperties();
   private final String jobVersion = "0.1";
   private final String jobName = "LHCM_FX";
   private final String projectName = "CETEMCO";
   public Integer errorCode = null;
   private String currentComponent = "";
   private final Map<String, Long> start_Hash = new HashMap();
   private final Map<String, Long> end_Hash = new HashMap();
   private final Map<String, Boolean> ok_Hash = new HashMap();
   private final Map<String, Object> globalMap = new HashMap();
   public final List<String[]> globalBuffer = new ArrayList();
   private final ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   private final PrintStream errorMessagePS;
   private Exception exception;
   public String resuming_logs_dir_path;
   public String resuming_checkpoint_path;
   public String parent_part_launcher;
   private String resumeEntryMethodName;
   private boolean globalResumeTicket;
   public boolean watch;
   public Integer portStats;
   public int portTraces;
   public String clientHost;
   public String defaultClientHost;
   public String contextStr;
   public String pid;
   public String rootPid;
   public String fatherPid;
   public String fatherNode;
   public long startTime;
   public boolean isChildJob;
   private boolean execStat;
   private ThreadLocal threadLocal;
   private Properties context_param;
   public Map<String, Object> parentContextMap;
   public String status;
   ResumeUtil resumeUtil;

   public LHCM_FX() {
      this.errorMessagePS = new PrintStream(new BufferedOutputStream(this.baos));
      this.exception = null;
      this.resuming_logs_dir_path = null;
      this.resuming_checkpoint_path = null;
      this.parent_part_launcher = null;
      this.resumeEntryMethodName = null;
      this.globalResumeTicket = false;
      this.watch = false;
      this.portStats = null;
      this.portTraces = 4334;
      this.defaultClientHost = "localhost";
      this.contextStr = "Default";
      this.pid = "0";
      this.rootPid = null;
      this.fatherPid = null;
      this.fatherNode = null;
      this.startTime = 0L;
      this.isChildJob = false;
      this.execStat = true;
      this.threadLocal = new ThreadLocal();
      Map threadRunResultMap = new HashMap();
      threadRunResultMap.put("errorCode", (Object)null);
      threadRunResultMap.put("status", "");
      this.threadLocal.set(threadRunResultMap);
      this.context_param = new Properties();
      this.parentContextMap = new HashMap();
      this.status = "";
      this.resumeUtil = null;
   }

   public Object getValueObject() {
      return this.valueObject;
   }

   public void setValueObject(Object valueObject) {
      this.valueObject = valueObject;
   }

   public LHCM_FX.ContextProperties getContext() {
      return this.context;
   }

   public String getExceptionStackTrace() {
      if ("failure".equals(this.getStatus())) {
         this.errorMessagePS.flush();
         return this.baos.toString();
      } else {
         return null;
      }
   }

   public Exception getException() {
      return "failure".equals(this.getStatus()) ? this.exception : null;
   }

   public void tJavaFlex_1_error(Exception exception, String errorComponent, Map<String, Object> globalMap) throws LHCM_FX.TalendException {
      this.end_Hash.put("tJavaFlex_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
      this.tJavaFlex_1_onSubJobError(exception, errorComponent, globalMap);
   }

   public void tLogRow_1_error(Exception exception, String errorComponent, Map<String, Object> globalMap) throws LHCM_FX.TalendException {
      this.end_Hash.put("tLogRow_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
      this.tJavaFlex_1_onSubJobError(exception, errorComponent, globalMap);
   }

   public void tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1_error(Exception exception, String errorComponent, Map<String, Object> globalMap) throws LHCM_FX.TalendException {
      this.end_Hash.put("tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
      this.tJavaFlex_1_onSubJobError(exception, errorComponent, globalMap);
   }

   public void tJavaFlex_1_onSubJobError(Exception exception, String errorComponent, Map<String, Object> globalMap) throws LHCM_FX.TalendException {
      this.resumeUtil.addLog("SYSTEM_LOG", "NODE:" + errorComponent, "", String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "FATAL", "", exception.getMessage(), ResumeUtil.getExceptionStackTrace(exception), "");
   }

   public void tJavaFlex_1Process(Map<String, Object> globalMap) throws LHCM_FX.TalendException {
      globalMap.put("tJavaFlex_1_SUBPROCESS_STATE", 0);
      boolean execStat = this.execStat;
      String iterateId = "";
      String currentComponent = "";

      try {
         String currentMethodName = (new Exception()).getStackTrace()[0].getMethodName();
         boolean resumeIt = currentMethodName.equals(this.resumeEntryMethodName);
         if (this.resumeEntryMethodName == null || resumeIt || this.globalResumeTicket) {
            this.globalResumeTicket = true;
            LHCM_FX.row1Struct row1 = new LHCM_FX.row1Struct();
            this.ok_Hash.put("tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1", false);
            this.start_Hash.put("tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
            currentComponent = "tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1";
            int tos_count_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = 0;
            DataSet dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = new DataSet();
            dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addColumn("sdcid", 0);
            dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addColumn("keyid1", 0);
            dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addColumn("paramlistid", 0);
            dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addColumn("variantid", 0);
            dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addColumn("paramtype", 0);
            dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addColumn("instrumentfield", 0);
            dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addColumn("value", 0);
            this.ok_Hash.put("tLogRow_1", false);
            this.start_Hash.put("tLogRow_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
            currentComponent = "tLogRow_1";
            int tos_count_tLogRow_1 = 0;
            this.ok_Hash.put("tJavaFlex_1", false);
            this.start_Hash.put("tJavaFlex_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
            currentComponent = "tJavaFlex_1";
            int tos_count_tJavaFlex_1 = 0;
            DataSet ds = LHCM_FX_ROUTINE.parseFXFile(this.context.filepath);

            int i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1;
            String keyid1;
            String instrumentfield;
            for(int i = 0; i < ds.getRowCount(); ++i) {
               currentComponent = "tJavaFlex_1";
               row1.sdcid = ds.getValue(i, "sdcid", "");
               row1.keyid1 = ds.getValue(i, "keyid1", "");
               row1.paramlistid = ds.getValue(i, "paramlistid", "");
               row1.variantid = ds.getValue(i, "variantid", "");
               row1.paramtype = ds.getValue(i, "paramtype", "");
               row1.instrumentfield = ds.getValue(i, "instrumentfield", "");
               row1.value = ds.getValue(i, "value", "");
               ++tos_count_tJavaFlex_1;
               currentComponent = "tLogRow_1";
               ++tos_count_tLogRow_1;
               currentComponent = "tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1";
               i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.addRow();
               keyid1 = "";
               instrumentfield = "";
               keyid1 = "sdcid";
               instrumentfield = row1.sdcid;
               instrumentfield = instrumentfield == null ? "" : instrumentfield;
               dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.setValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, keyid1, instrumentfield);
               keyid1 = "keyid1";
               instrumentfield = row1.keyid1;
               instrumentfield = instrumentfield == null ? "" : instrumentfield;
               dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.setValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, keyid1, instrumentfield);
               keyid1 = "paramlistid";
               instrumentfield = row1.paramlistid;
               instrumentfield = instrumentfield == null ? "" : instrumentfield;
               dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.setValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, keyid1, instrumentfield);
               keyid1 = "variantid";
               instrumentfield = row1.variantid;
               instrumentfield = instrumentfield == null ? "" : instrumentfield;
               dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.setValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, keyid1, instrumentfield);
               keyid1 = "paramtype";
               instrumentfield = row1.paramtype;
               instrumentfield = instrumentfield == null ? "" : instrumentfield;
               dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.setValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, keyid1, instrumentfield);
               keyid1 = "instrumentfield";
               instrumentfield = row1.instrumentfield;
               instrumentfield = instrumentfield == null ? "" : instrumentfield;
               dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.setValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, keyid1, instrumentfield);
               keyid1 = "value";
               instrumentfield = row1.value;
               instrumentfield = instrumentfield == null ? "" : instrumentfield;
               dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.setValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, keyid1, instrumentfield);
               ++tos_count_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1;
               currentComponent = "tJavaFlex_1";
            }

            this.ok_Hash.put("tJavaFlex_1", true);
            this.end_Hash.put("tJavaFlex_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
            currentComponent = "tLogRow_1";
            this.ok_Hash.put("tLogRow_1", true);
            this.end_Hash.put("tLogRow_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
            currentComponent = "tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1";
            String sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = "";
            if ("LIMS CI".equals("LIMS CI") && (!dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.isValidColumn("sdcid") || !dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.isValidColumn("keyid1") || !dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.isValidColumn("instrumentfield") || !dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.isValidColumn("value"))) {
               sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 + "Error : In 'LIMS CI' case, the columns sdcid, keyid1, instrumentfield and value are mandatory. Please change the component schema.";
            }

            if ("LIMS CI".equals("Protocol Provider") && (!dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.isValidColumn("instrumentfield") || !dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.isValidColumn("value"))) {
               sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 + "Error : In 'Protocol Provider' case, the columns instrumentfield and value are mandatory. Please change the component schema.";
            }

            if (sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.equals("")) {
               for(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = 0; i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 < dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.getRowCount(); ++i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1) {
                  keyid1 = dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.getValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, "keyid1", "null");
                  instrumentfield = dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.getValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, "instrumentfield", "null");
                  if ((!"LIMS CI".equals("LIMS CI") || !keyid1.equals("null")) && !instrumentfield.equals("null")) {
                     for(int j_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = 0; j_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 < dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.getColumnCount(); ++j_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1) {
                        String columnid = dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.getColumnId(j_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1);
                        String value = dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.getValue(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1, columnid, "nullvalue");
                        String message = "";
                        if ("LIMS CI".equals("LIMS CI") && (columnid.equals("sdcid") || columnid.equals("keyid1") || columnid.equals("instrumentfield")) && (value == null || value.equals("") || value.equals("nullvalue"))) {
                           message = "Error : Invalid value : The column '" + columnid + "' can not be empty or null.\n";
                           if (!sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.contains(message)) {
                              sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 + message;
                           }
                        }

                        if ("LIMS CI".equals("Protocol Provider")) {
                           if (!columnid.equals("instrumentfield") && !columnid.equals("value")) {
                              message = "Error : Invalid column '" + columnid + "'. In 'Protocol Provider' case, only 'instrumentfield' and 'value' columns are accepted.\n";
                              if (!sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.contains(message)) {
                                 sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 + message;
                              }
                           } else if (columnid.equals("instrumentfield") && (value == null || value.equals("") || value.equals("nullvalue"))) {
                              message = "Error : Invalid value : The column '" + columnid + "' can not be empty or null.\n";
                              if (!sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.contains(message)) {
                                 sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 = sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1 + message;
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  } else {
                     dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.deleteRow(i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1);
                     --i_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1;
                  }
               }
            }

            if (!sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.equals("")) {
               System.out.println("Invalid data ! You must solve the following problems : ");
               System.out.println(sWarningMessages_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1);
            }

            System.out.println("xmldataset=" + dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.toXML());
            globalMap.put("tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1_NB_LINE", dsData_tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1.getRowCount());
            this.ok_Hash.put("tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1", true);
            this.end_Hash.put("tLabVantageLIMSCIPostData_1", System.currentTimeMillis());
         }
      } catch (Exception var22) {
         throw new LHCM_FX.TalendException(var22, currentComponent, globalMap, (LHCM_FX.TalendException)null);
      } catch (Error var23) {
         throw new Error(var23);
      }

      globalMap.put("tJavaFlex_1_SUBPROCESS_STATE", 1);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      LHCM_FX LHCM_FXClass = new LHCM_FX();
      int exitCode = LHCM_FXClass.runJobInTOS(args);
      System.exit(exitCode);
   }

   public String[][] runJob(String[] args) {
      int exitCode = this.runJobInTOS(args);
      String[][] bufferValue = new String[][]{{Integer.toString(exitCode)}};
      return bufferValue;
   }

   public int runJobInTOS(String[] args) {
      String lastStr = "";
      boolean hasContextArg = false;
      String[] var7 = args;
      int var6 = args.length;

      for(int var5 = 0; var5 < var6; ++var5) {
         String arg = var7[var5];
         if (arg.toLowerCase().contains("--context=")) {
            hasContextArg = true;
         } else if (arg.equalsIgnoreCase("--context_param")) {
            lastStr = arg;
         } else if (lastStr.equals("")) {
            this.evalParam(arg);
         } else {
            this.evalParam(lastStr + " " + arg);
            lastStr = "";
         }
      }

      if (this.clientHost == null) {
         this.clientHost = this.defaultClientHost;
      }

      if (this.pid == null || "0".equals(this.pid)) {
         this.pid = TalendString.getAsciiRandomString(6);
      }

      if (this.rootPid == null) {
         this.rootPid = this.pid;
      }

      if (this.fatherPid == null) {
         this.fatherPid = this.pid;
      } else {
         this.isChildJob = true;
      }

      try {
         InputStream inContext = LHCM_FX.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("cetemco/lhcm_fx_0_1/contexts/" + this.contextStr + ".properties");
         if (inContext != null) {
            this.defaultProps.load(inContext);
            inContext.close();
            this.context = new LHCM_FX.ContextProperties(this.defaultProps);
         } else if (hasContextArg) {
            System.err.println("Could not find the context " + this.contextStr);
         }

         if (!this.context_param.isEmpty()) {
            this.context.putAll(this.context_param);
         }

         this.context.filepath = this.context.getProperty("filepath");
      } catch (IOException var12) {
         System.err.println("Could not load context " + this.contextStr);
         var12.printStackTrace();
      }

      if (this.parentContextMap != null && !this.parentContextMap.isEmpty() && this.parentContextMap.containsKey("filepath")) {
         this.context.filepath = (String)this.parentContextMap.get("filepath");
      }

      this.resumeEntryMethodName = ResumeUtil.getResumeEntryMethodName(this.resuming_checkpoint_path);
      this.resumeUtil = new ResumeUtil(this.resuming_logs_dir_path, this.isChildJob, this.rootPid);
      this.resumeUtil.initCommonInfo(this.pid, this.rootPid, this.fatherPid, "CETEMCO", "LHCM_FX", this.contextStr, "0.1");
      this.resumeUtil.addLog("JOB_STARTED", "JOB:LHCM_FX", this.parent_part_launcher, String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "", "", "", "", ResumeUtil.convertToJsonText(this.context));
      long startUsedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
      long endUsedMemory = 0L;
      long end = 0L;
      this.startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      this.globalResumeTicket = true;
      this.globalResumeTicket = false;

      try {
         this.errorCode = null;
         this.tJavaFlex_1Process(this.globalMap);
         this.status = "end";
      } catch (LHCM_FX.TalendException var11) {
         this.status = "failure";
         var11.printStackTrace();
         this.globalMap.put("tJavaFlex_1_SUBPROCESS_STATE", -1);
      }

      this.globalResumeTicket = true;
      end = System.currentTimeMillis();
      if (this.watch) {
         System.out.println(end - this.startTime + " milliseconds");
      }

      endUsedMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory() - Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory();
      int returnCode = false;
      int returnCode;
      if (this.errorCode == null) {
         returnCode = this.status != null && this.status.equals("failure") ? 1 : 0;
      } else {
         returnCode = this.errorCode;
      }

      this.resumeUtil.addLog("JOB_ENDED", "JOB:LHCM_FX", this.parent_part_launcher, String.valueOf(Thread.currentThread().getId()), "", "" + returnCode, "", "", "");
      return returnCode;
   }

   private void evalParam(String arg) {
      if (arg.startsWith("--resuming_logs_dir_path")) {
         this.resuming_logs_dir_path = arg.substring(25);
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--resuming_checkpoint_path")) {
         this.resuming_checkpoint_path = arg.substring(27);
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--parent_part_launcher")) {
         this.parent_part_launcher = arg.substring(23);
      } else if (arg.startsWith("--watch")) {
         this.watch = true;
      } else {
         String keyValue;
         if (arg.startsWith("--stat_port=")) {
            keyValue = arg.substring(12);
            if (keyValue != null && !keyValue.equals("null")) {
               this.portStats = Integer.parseInt(keyValue);
            }
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--trace_port=")) {
            this.portTraces = Integer.parseInt(arg.substring(13));
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--client_host=")) {
            this.clientHost = arg.substring(14);
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--context=")) {
            this.contextStr = arg.substring(10);
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--father_pid=")) {
            this.fatherPid = arg.substring(13);
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--root_pid=")) {
            this.rootPid = arg.substring(11);
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--father_node=")) {
            this.fatherNode = arg.substring(14);
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--pid=")) {
            this.pid = arg.substring(6);
         } else if (arg.startsWith("--context_param")) {
            keyValue = arg.substring(16);
            int index = true;
            int index;
            if (keyValue != null && (index = keyValue.indexOf(61)) > -1) {
               this.context_param.put(keyValue.substring(0, index), keyValue.substring(index + 1));
            }
         }
      }

   }

   public Integer getErrorCode() {
      return this.errorCode;
   }

   public String getStatus() {
      return this.status;
   }

   public class ContextProperties extends Properties {
      public String filepath;

      public ContextProperties(Properties properties) {
         super(properties);
      }

      public ContextProperties() {
      }

      public void synchronizeContext() {
         if (this.filepath != null) {
            this.setProperty("filepath", this.filepath.toString());
         }

      }

      public String getFilepath() {
         return this.filepath;
      }
   }

   private class TalendException extends Exception {
      private Map<String, Object> globalMap;
      private Exception e;
      private String currentComponent;

      private TalendException(Exception e, String errorComponent, Map<String, Object> globalMap) {
         this.globalMap = null;
         this.e = null;
         this.currentComponent = null;
         this.currentComponent = errorComponent;
         this.globalMap = globalMap;
         this.e = e;
      }

      public void printStackTrace() {
         if (!(this.e instanceof LHCM_FX.TalendException) && !(this.e instanceof TDieException)) {
            this.globalMap.put(this.currentComponent + "_ERROR_MESSAGE", this.e.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Exception in component " + this.currentComponent);
         }

         if (!(this.e instanceof TDieException)) {
            if (this.e instanceof LHCM_FX.TalendException) {
               this.e.printStackTrace();
            } else {
               this.e.printStackTrace();
               this.e.printStackTrace(LHCM_FX.this.errorMessagePS);
               LHCM_FX.this.exception = this.e;
            }
         }

         if (!(this.e instanceof LHCM_FX.TalendException)) {
            try {
               Method[] var4;
               int var3 = (var4 = this.getClass().getEnclosingClass().getMethods()).length;

               for(int var2 = 0; var2 < var3; ++var2) {
                  Method m = var4[var2];
                  if (m.getName().compareTo(this.currentComponent + "_error") == 0) {
                     m.invoke(LHCM_FX.this, this.e, this.currentComponent, this.globalMap);
                     break;
                  }
               }

               boolean var10000 = this.e instanceof TDieException;
            } catch (SecurityException var5) {
               this.e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException var6) {
               this.e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalAccessException var7) {
               this.e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (InvocationTargetException var8) {
               this.e.printStackTrace();
            }
         }

      }






 // ............. More More code












   }
}
```

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Your question is not clear could you explain your purpose ?

Comment: I would like please to know how to call     filepath        in my first java class    as called in the big second java class ?  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

My bad!

I have the parameter filepath inside args of my :    MAIN (String[] args)

so filepath = args[4]

Im sorry and thanks anyway :)